# Visual Studio refactor-rename causes inexplicable global replace of attributes in XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, refactoring

I feel like I must be going crazy, but I just changed the name of a property in a view model (a C# file) from `Width` to `Size` using Visual Studio's refactor-rename feature. When I was done, this error appeared in the Error window:

> Error 2: The property 'Size' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.

The error was referring to a XAML `UserControl` file. When I checked the file to see what was up, I realized that every attribute named `Width` had been changed to `Size`.

Example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ApbSymbolGenerator.Views.Symbol"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Size="{Binding Size}"
             Height="{Binding Size}">
```

This is the first time I've ever had refactor-rename cause a change to a XAML file (besides the `x:class` value). (Note: I did *not* do a global find/replace, I did refactor-rename. I undid everything and performed the rename again, and it did the same thing.)

Strangely, it only affected one of several XAML files in my app that has a `Width` property.

Any explanation what could be going on here?

Comment: Way to go WPF, break all our favourite features: refactoring, Go To Definition, not being silent about fatal errors, strong static typing, the ability to comment out arbitrary code, whatever else I forgot.

Comment: Even now, I would not fully trust refactoring code in visual studio. Make sure you BACK UP YOUR ENTIRE SOLUTION prior to any major refactoring. It has been known to replace unrelated symbols from time to time. I've had it refactor "all occurances of" a const of ABC with XYZ and then it replaces stuff unrelated. Example, I'll find a rogue Item.Name that has been changed to Item.ABC though it is completely irrelevant and definitely didn't previously go by Item.XYZ.  Never fully trust ANYTHING that does mass changes to your project, EVER, even if God himself wrote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug (that won't be fixed) - [Refactor Rename Bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/656466/refactor-rename-bug/)